# .htaccess redirect only for resources

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, resources, subdirectory

i'm trying a solution to have something like that:

```
/dev/base/route.php -> include "/dev/base/mysite/index.php"
```

for php of course i've no problem using this system , all code is properly working, but for html tags ( such as `<img` , `<link` etc.. ) i need to redirect the requests to `./dev/base/mysite/` directory.

I'm trying to solve it using htaccess (without changing url bar), using this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /mysite/$0 -f
RewriteCond /mysite/$0 -d
RewriteRule ^$ /mysite/$0 [L]
```

but it doesn't work. ( i'm not very skilled in mod_rewrite )

also, i cannot specify `/dev/base/` path statically in htaccess file, it should be solved "automatically" because it can change according to workstation.

so i need something that in pseudo-php code syntax should resemble it:

```
if ( file_exists(SITE_ROOT_DIR."/mysite/".$request) && !file_exists(SITE_ROOT_DIR."/".$request) )
   $url=SITE_ROOT_DIR."/mysite/".$request;
else
   $url=SITE_ROOT_DIR."/".$request;
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this:

```
RewriteBase /dev/base/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dev/base/mysite/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dev/base/mysite/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dev/base/mysite/$1 -l
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ mysite/$1 [L]
```

Comment: but %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} doesn't contain **/dev/path/**  too ( that is where htaccess resides ) so i need to add it manually, instead i would find out automatically

Comment: Pls tell me what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT and where does this .htaccess reside?

Comment: my document root is home/workspace/  and my .htaccess is inside /home/workspace/dev/base/  , i need this structure

Comment: Then what exactly is mysite?

Comment: /mysite/ is a subdirectory of /home/workspace/dev/base/ where i've all folders such as images, css etc...but they must result like they are in /home/workspace/dev/base/ instead , using htaccess ( no symlink or other workarounds ) ..
take a look at my pseudo-code, it's quite clear

Comment: All the confusion started because of your pseudo code only. You wrote `SITE_ROOT_DIR."/mysite/"` there however now you commented that mysite is actually `DOCUMENT_ROOT/dev/base/mysite`. Anyway I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: the fact is that i cannot specify /dev/base/ inside htaccess because this path can change according to the machine where the code is installed, instead the htaccess file must be the same.
So, isn't there a way to get the path of .htaccess file? or just using relative paths instead absolute in condition rows..?

Comment: Actually the whole reason these rules are there in .htaccess so that you don't need to touch your application code while deploying. People just keep different .htaccess to manage dev, staging and production sites working.